# Cannot install Archive::Zip with Cpan

Tags: perl, cpan

I am trying to install Archive::Zip with the following command:

```
cpan[3]> install Archive::Zip
```

However it never gets installed. I am not sure what to do next. Here is the log I get:

```
Running install for module 'Archive::Zip'
Running make for P/PH/PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.58.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/Archive-Zip-1.58-1OzAcc
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----       PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.58.tar.gz      ----
    Test::MockModule [requires]
Running make test
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running install for module 'Test::MockModule'
Running Build for G/GF/GFRANKS/Test-MockModule-0.11.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/Test-MockModule-0.11-_LrG4F
  '/usr/bin/perl Build.PL ' returned status 512, won't make
Running Build test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running Build install
  Make had some problems, won't install
Running make for P/PH/PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.58.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /root/.cpan/build/Archive-Zip-1.58-1OzAcc
Warning: Prerequisite 'Test::MockModule => 0' for 'PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.58.tar.gz' failed when processing 'GFRANKS/Test-MockModule-0.11.tar.gz' with 'writemakefile => NO '/usr/bin/perl Build.PL ' returned status 512'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
  Has already been made
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/01_compile.t ................ ok
t/02_main.t ................... ok
t/03_ex.t ..................... ok
t/04_readmember.t ............. ok
t/05_tree.t ................... ok
t/06_update.t ................. ok
t/07_filenames_of_0.t ......... ok
t/08_readmember_record_sep.t .. ok
t/09_output_record_sep.t ...... ok
t/10_chmod.t .................. ok
t/11_explorer.t ............... ok
t/12_bug_47223.t .............. skipped: Only required on Win32.
t/13_bug_46303.t .............. ok
t/14_leading_separator.t ...... ok
t/15_decrypt.t ................ ok
t/16_decrypt.t ................ ok
t/17_101092.t ................. ok
t/18_bug_92205.t .............. ok
t/19_bug_101240.t ............. ok
t/20_bug_github11.t ........... ok
t/21_zip64.t .................. ok
t/22_deflated_dir.t ........... ok
t/23_closed_handle.t .......... Can't locate Test/MockModule.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /root/.cpan/build/Archive-Zip-1.58-1OzAcc/blib/lib /root/.cpan/build/Archive-Zip-1.58-1OzAcc/blib/arch /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at t/23_closed_handle.t line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at t/23_closed_handle.t line 9.
t/23_closed_handle.t .......... Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
No subtests run
t/24_unicode_win32.t .......... ok
```

And here is the test summary after I the installation:

```
Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/23_closed_handle.t        (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: No plan found in TAP output
Files=24, Tests=302,  2 wallclock secs ( 0.07 usr  0.01 sys +  1.72 cusr  0.28 csys =  2.08 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/24 test programs. 0/302 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.58.tar.gz
one dependency not OK (Test::MockModule); additionally test harness failed
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.58.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 PHRED/Archive-Zip-1.58.tar.gz                : make_test NO one dependency not OK (Test::MockModule); additionally test harness failed
```

Here is my o conf of cpan.pm:

```
cpan[2]> o conf
$CPAN::Config options from /root/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm:
    commit             [Commit changes to disk]
    defaults           [Reload defaults from disk]
    help               [Short help about 'o conf' usage]
    init               [Interactive setting of all options]

    applypatch         []
    auto_commit        [0]
    build_cache        [100]
    build_dir          [/root/.cpan/build]
    build_dir_reuse    [0]
    build_requires_install_policy [yes]
    bzip2              [/usr/bin/bzip2]
    cache_metadata     [1]
    check_sigs         [0]
    colorize_debug     undef
    colorize_output    undef
    colorize_print     undef
    colorize_warn      undef
    commandnumber_in_prompt [1]
    commands_quote     undef
    connect_to_internet_ok [1]
    cpan_home          [/root/.cpan]
    curl               undef
    dontload_hash      undef
    dontload_list      undef
    ftp                undef
    ftp_passive        [1]
    ftp_proxy          []
    ftpstats_period    undef
    ftpstats_size      undef
    getcwd             [cwd]
    gpg                [/usr/bin/gpg]
    gzip               [/usr/bin/gzip]
    halt_on_failure    [0]
    histfile           [/root/.cpan/histfile]
    histsize           [100]
    http_proxy         []
    inactivity_timeout [0]
    index_expire       [1]
    inhibit_startup_message [0]
    keep_source_where  [/root/.cpan/sources]
    load_module_verbosity [none]
    lynx               undef
    make               [/usr/bin/make]
    make_arg           []
    make_install_arg   []
    make_install_make_command [sudo /usr/bin/make]
    makepl_arg         []
    mbuild_arg         []
    mbuild_install_arg []
    mbuild_install_build_command [sudo ./Build]
    mbuildpl_arg       []
    ncftp              undef
    ncftpget           undef
    no_proxy           []
    pager              [/usr/bin/less]
    password           undef
    patch              []
    patches_dir        undef
    perl5lib_verbosity [none]
    prefer_external_tar [1]
    prefer_installer   [MB]
    prefs_dir          [/root/.cpan/prefs]
    prerequisites_policy [follow]
    proxy_pass         undef
    proxy_user         undef
    randomize_urllist  undef
    scan_cache         [atstart]
    shell              [/bin/bash]
    show_unparsable_versions [0]
    show_upload_date   [0]
    show_zero_versions [0]
    tar                [/usr/bin/tar]
    tar_verbosity      [none]
    term_is_latin      [1]
    term_ornaments     [1]
    test_report        [0]
    trust_test_report_history [0]
    unzip              [/usr/bin/unzip]
    urllist
        0 [http://cpan.perl-hackers.net/]
        1 [http://download.xs4all.nl/CPAN/]
        2 [http://cpan.mirrors.uk2.net/]
    use_sqlite         [0]
    username           undef
    version_timeout    [15]
    wait_list          undef
    wget               [/usr/bin/wget]
    yaml_load_code     [0]
    yaml_module        [YAML]
```

I am using CentOS.

Comment: Can you provide more information on the particular system? In your case the error says it's missing Test::MockModule. You can try and install it beforehand, although maybe that one needs some external dependency. On the other hand, I have been able to install it using cpanm in Ubuntu without a problem, so we need more info to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @jjmerelo added the conf

Comment: still no clue about Perl version or operating system. Anyway, whenever some dependency fails, try to install it by itself, to see exactly what's the problem. If you are using Linux (which you should), it might be prepackaged for that particular distribution, which saves the hassle of installing external dependencies. In that particular case, `libtest-mockmodule-perl - Perl module to override subroutines in a module for unit testing`. So, try and install it from operating system repos, that fails, do cpan Test::MockModule, that fails, it will give you a clue of what's the problem.

Comment: @jjmerelo I actually added that I am using CentOS. Will try your solution anyway.

Comment: Try this: `look Test::MockModule`, then `perl Build.PL`

Comment: Try yum list MockModule to see if it's available (it does not seem to be), and then proceed to install it by itself as above, checking out what seems to be the problem with it. Which version of CentOS are you using? Anyway, that module does not seem to have been tested for CentOS http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/T/Test-MockModule.html#Test-MockModule-0.11 so your mileage might vary.

Comment: @rustyx test::mockmodule says no such file or directory. There are 4 different build.pl: ./.cpan/build/Test-MockModule-0.11-_LrG4F/Build.PL
./.cpan/build/Test-MockModule-0.11-ELO8uh/Build.PL
./.cpan/build/Text-Reform-1.20-awzh_H/Build.PL
./.cpan/build/Test-MockModule-0.11-SU5BkX/Build.PL

Comment: @jjmerelo I am using CentOS 7

Comment: Good for you, but please try what I said above. Also, those dirs you list above are failed installation dirs for that module. Get into any one of them and try what @rustyx mentioned, to see what seems to be the problem with that specific module. Might be some CentOS quirk, might be some external dependency you might have to install by itself, that is why you should first try and have `yum` take care of everything by installing that module from OS repos if possible.

Comment: @prgrm try either one. `cd ./.cpan/build/Test-MockModule-0.11-_LrG4F/; perl Build.PL`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
cpan -f Archive::Zip
```

I believe I ran into this problem a few weeks ago, and it was just the test suite that was busted. The module worked fine. YMMV